# Regex ignore everything after a character

Tags: regex

I have following regex.

```
^(.*[^0-9])([0-9A-Fa-f]{8}[-]?[0-9A-Fa-f]{4}[-]?[0-9A-Fa-f]{4}[-]?[0-9A-Fa-f]{4}[-]?[0-9A-Fa-f]{12})(.*)$
```

It splits a given text into 3 groups. `1:Pre-GUID`, `2:GUID` and `3:post-GUID` text.

```
Input: /user/questions/9c8a8823-d88c-4402-a2c1-4530a966f993/help

Results:
Group 1: /user/questions/
Group 2: 9c8a8823-d88c-4402-a2c1-4530a966f993
Group 3: /help
```

However, I have some instances where GUID is followed by a special character such as `@` and in that case I want to ignore everything after GUID ignored i.e. 3rd group that is post GUID be empty.

```
Input: /user/questions/9c8a8823-d88c-4402-a2c1-4530a966f993@help

Results:
Group 1: /user/questions/
Group 2: 9c8a8823-d88c-4402-a2c1-4530a966f993
Group 3:
```

In other terms i don't want regex to consider anything if it encounters a `@`.

Comment: Your second sample doesn't match your explanation? There is no `@` anywhere? Was it supposed to be where the colon is? Or is the colon another case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, if the last part of the string is `:<whatever>` or `@<whatever>` the group 3 should be empty:

```
^(.*[^0-9])([0-9A-Fa-f]{8}[-]?[0-9A-Fa-f]{4}[-]?[0-9A-Fa-f]{4}[-]?[0-9A-Fa-f]{4}[-]?[0-9A-Fa-f]{12})([^:@].*$|)
```

[Regex demo.](https://regex101.com/r/T2DpBR/1)

---

Only the last group is changed to `([^:@].*$|)` - match any character but `:`/`@` to end of string or match empty string.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the third group to be *none*, you may replace it with:

```
([^@:].*$)?
```

If you want the third group to be *empty*, you may use:

```
([^@:].*$|)
```

This will look for either `@` or `:`. You may add more characters to the negated character class as needed.

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/df0exM/1)**.

---

There's one more improvement that I feel inclined to recommend though. Currently, your pattern will match GUID's that have hyphens in some places but not others. To fix this, we can add the first hyphen in a capturing group and replace the subsequent ones with a backreference:

```
^(.*[^0-9])([0-9A-Fa-f]{8}(-?)[0-9A-Fa-f]{4}\3[0-9A-Fa-f]{4}\3[0-9A-Fa-f]{4}\3[0-9A-Fa-f]{12})([^@:].*$)?
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/EPkvoo/1)**.

Note that in this case, the last part will be in group 4 instead of group 3.

Comment: The backtracking isn't optimal either. This should be faster: `^(?>(.*?…)(…))([^@].*$)?` (atomic group + laziness)